# pyparsing nested structure not working as expected

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a simple JSON-like structure into python dics and then turn it into a proper JSON structure. The block is as follows:

```
###################################################
# HEADER TEXT
# HEADER TEXT
###################################################
NAME => {
    NAME              => VALUE,
    NAME              => VALUE,
    NAME                => VALUE,
    NAME     => {
        NAME => {
            NAME        => VALUE,  NAME => VALUE,  NAME => VALUE,
        },
    } # comment 
}, # more comments
```

and repeating. Rules:

```
NAME = alphanums and _
VALUE = decimal(6) | hex (0xA) | list of hex ([0x1,0x2]) | text in brackets([A]) | string("A")
```

I set up the following grammar:

```
cfgName = Word(alphanums+"_")
cfgString = dblQuotedString().setParseAction(removeQuotes)
cfgNumber = Word("0123456789ABCDEFx")

LBRACK, RBRACK, LBRACE, RBRACE = map(Suppress, "[]{}")
EQUAL = Literal('=>').suppress()

cfgObject = Forward()
cfgValue = Forward()
cfgElements = delimitedList(cfgValue)
cfgArray = Group(LBRACK + Optional(cfgElements, []) + RBRACK)
cfgValue << (cfgString | cfgNumber | cfgArray | cfgName | Group(cfgObject))
memberDef = Group(cfgName + EQUAL + cfgValue)
cfgMembers = delimitedList(memberDef)
cfgObject << Dict(LBRACE + Optional(cfgMembers) + RBRACE)
cfgComment = pythonStyleComment 
cfgObject.ignore(cfgComment)
```

EDIT: I've managed to isolate the problem. Proper JSON is

```
{member,member,member}
```

however my structure is:

```
{member,member,member,}
```

the  last element in every nested structure is comma separated and I don't know how to account for that in the grammar.

Comment: Not tested, but would this do it? "cfgMembers = delimitedList(memberDef) + Optional(Suppress(','))"

Comment: It did! Thanks. Now I only need to somehow seperate the hex value from regular numbers. I tried hex = Word(hexnums+"x") but it interferes with decimal numbers

Comment: Make your hex number more specific than just "Word(hexnums+'x')" That expression would match any word with hex numbers and 'x's in it, even just 'xxx'. Define hexnumber specifically as "hexNumber = Combine("0x" + Word(hexnums))", and include it in cfgValue *before* cfgNumber (so that the leading '0' is not misparsed as the integer 0). Many times a parser can be tightened up by changing overly matchable Word expressions into more specific ones.

Comment: How would you define the grammar of : `<<'EOT'
text text text EOT`? I tried `Literal("<<'EOT'") + SkipTo('EOT')` but it doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: Be sure to add the trailing 'EOT' into your parser, it is not included in SkipTo by default. Either use 'include=True' in your SkipTo, or add it on the end with "+ 'EOT'".

Comment: Thanks for the help! you have made a great tool.